# Cannot connect to database from a .jar file

Tags: eclipse, ms-access, jar, connection, runnable

I'm trying to save a Java project in Eclipse as a jar file.

As I'm working with an Access database and I should export everything, I decided to include the database file in the same folder as `Main.class` and `SingletonConnection.class` (which is the class that manages the connection with the database).

So the code is:

```
private SingletonConnection()throws ConnessioneException{

    idConnection = "root";
    passConnection = "";

    String slash="\\";
    String path=this.getClass().getResource("").getPath().replaceFirst("^.*:", "").replaceFirst("!.*$", "").replace("/", slash.concat("\\"));

    System.out.println("path è "+path);

    driverConnection = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    stringConnection = "jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:"+path+"eventi.mdb";


    try {
        Class.forName(driverConnection);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConnection,idConnection,passConnection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ConnessioneException();
    }
}

public static Connection getInstance()throws ConnessioneException{
    if(conn==null)
        new SingletonConnection();

    return conn; 
}
```

In Eclipse everything is ok.  The project works and no exceptions, but when I try to export the project as a Runnable Jar File or a Jar File it always returns `ConnessioneException =null` so the connection to the db fails.

**Exception is given in the method getInstance, line "new SingletonConnection()"**

I need to run that program on other PCs, so I need to solve that. I cannot continue using Eclipse.

Comment: What is the stacktrace? is the ODBC driver included in the jar file?

Comment: Just some advice, never do catch (Exception e) ...throw new ConnessioneException(); Always do something like throw new ConnessioneException("caught Exception", e); so you'll always have the root cause of the exception in the stacktrace.

Comment: thanks for the advice Matthew.. however as Thilo said i didn't include the drivers ..so i'm googling on how to do it ^^

Comment: i found that link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html ... what driver should I download? In eclipse it was already included..

Comment: which database do you have? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED :  maybe it can be useful for someone:

```
 ***   import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils; !!  (package: commons-io-2.1.jar)

    idConnection = "root";
    passConnection = "";

    String slash="\\";
    String path=null;

    String temp=System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    if ( !(temp.endsWith("/") || temp.endsWith("\\")) )
           temp = temp + System.getProperty("file.separator");
    File tempDir = new File(temp);
    File temporaryFile = new File(tempDir, "templateCopy.mdw");
    InputStream templateStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("eventi.mdw");
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(templateStream, new FileOutputStream(temporaryFile));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        //Dialog d1=new Dialog("filenotfound");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        //Dialog d2=new Dialog("io");
    }catch (Exception e1){
        //Dialog d3=new Dialog("general");
    }

    path = temporaryFile.getAbsolutePath();

    driverConnection = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    stringConnection = "jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+path;


    try {
        Class.forName(driverConnection);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(stringConnection,idConnection,passConnection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ConnessioneException(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```